# Using Ridge Regression to estimate importance of multicollinear variables in python

Tags: multiple-regression, pca, least-squares, multicollinearity, ridge-regression

New to statistical analysis so bear with me.
I have a dataset with 1 (say y) dependent variable and 5 independent variables (say x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) which are highly correlated. I know that y depends (linearly) on x5, but want to answer how much it also depends on x1 through x4 (which in theory should have increasing linear dependence).

I have done a PCA in python using sklearn and the method

```
PCA().explained_variance_ratio_
```

gives me some indication as to the relative importance of each independent variable (as far as I understand).

How do I do a similar analysis with ridge regression in sklearn? The resources I find online return only the best fit parameters, predict and/or find the coefficient of determination. Also any advice on this problem is much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to CV, Tom. It's hard to see how ridge regression would solve your problem. If you wish a correct answer to your original question, then simply regress $x_1,\ldots, x_4,$ and $y$ against $x_5,$ replace them with their five sets of residuals, and explore the relationships between the $y$ residuals and the other residuals: that's how you remove the effect of the variable $x_5.$  This is the basis of the "added variable plot" discussed in regression textbooks and available in some stats software.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your reply. Is this the same process as a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization? I've used this as a first test and would like some other metrics such as the PCA which (I think) tells me something about how much variance each independent variable is responsible for

Comment: PCA of the X values does not do what you think it does. It is simply a way to reduce the number of variables.  And it doesn't involve Y at all.  

Do you want the importance of the variables controlling for the others? This gets hard when there is collinearity. But you can (of course) look at 5 individual regressions to see which is important when NOT controlling for the others.

Comment: This is closely related to Gram-Schmidt.  But PCA will not do what you want, even when you include $Y$ among the variables.  Moreover, PCA isn't any kind of "metric" in the ordinary sense of the term (as a kind of distance function).  "Variance ... responsible for" is the language of *ordinary least squares regression,* pointing the way towards the simple resolution of your problem.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks for this - good to know. Yes, I want to know the importance of the variables controlling for the others. My hypothesis is that you need x1..x4 & x5 to accurately predict y, the alternative hypothesis is that only x5 is needed. However all x's are quite correlated. It would be enough for me to show (or prove otherwise) that you need more than one x feature to predict y to some confidence level. I was hoping that if all but one of my regression coefficients are close to zero this could somehow prove/disprove my hypothesis

Comment: @whuber thanks for your comments, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you wrote

> Yes, I want to know the importance of the variables controlling for
> the others. My hypothesis is that you need x1..x4 & x5 to accurately
> predict y, the alternative hypothesis is that only x5 is needed.

Then a practical approach is to run the regression with just x5 and with all the x's, and to compare the fitted values of each model to the actual values of y. You could plot these in various ways. You could also see how much smaller the summed absolute value of the residuals are in the more complex model.

I'm not so big on theory, but this seems to answer your question directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to be clear - by "run the regression" do you mean an OLS or ridge regression for the case with all the other x's to account for the multicollinearity of the independent variables?

Comment: I was thinking of OLS. But ridge might make more sense.

Comment: Final Q on your answer: Can I use the R^2 values to compare the OLS regression against just x5 and the ridge/OLS regression against all x's (model.score(x,y) in sklearn)) or will the addition of extra data pollute my R^2 value?

Comment: R^2 is proportion of variance explained by the model, which doesn't seem like exactly what you want.